# Request not recognized upload image

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, view, image-uploading

I'm having a problem to get images uploaded. I have a default image to all the users. And when i choose other image to change the default one, it doesn't work. Somehow the $request is not being recognized. 
The code of UserController:

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Image;

public function updateAvatar(Request $request){
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename=time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        if($user->avatar!='default.jgp'){
            $file = 'uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar;
            if(File::exists($file)){
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
        Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));
        $user= Auth::user();
        $user->avatar=$filename;
        $user->save();
    }
    return view('pages.AfterLogin.Entidade.users.profile')->withUser(Auth::user());
}
```

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: Make sure you are using PUT/PATCH method

Comment: I have post method @LeaTano

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile" method="post">
                      <label>Mudar foto</label>
                      <input type="file" name="avatar">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  </form>           @MMMTroy

Comment: `POST` method is for creating and `PUT/PATCH` for updating. Try to change `method="post"` to `method="put"` and please let me know.

Comment: if previous modifications does not work try to change the enctype to `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Some people are completing about the enctype. Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

Comment: you need to give a route or a file name in the action is profile your route???

Comment: I did that @LeaTano and didn't work out :(

Comment: Yes, profile is my route @Rohitshah

Answer (score 1):

use dd($request); and show the screenshot and show the form as well.

Comment: Where is < form enctype multipart/form-data>

Comment: I tried both.   multipart/form-data  and x-www-form-urlencoded @Ravi

Comment: i found it out. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your method is correct. Try this:

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Image;

public function updateAvatar(Request $request){
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename=time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        if($user->avatar!='default.jpg'){
            $file = 'uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar;
            if(File::exists($file)){
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
        Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));
        $user= Auth::user();
        $user->avatar=$filename;
        $user->save();
    }
    return view('pages.AfterLogin.Entidade.users.profile')->withUser(Auth::user());
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened as well :( @SSuhat

Comment: @JoãoCosta are you sure your form url is correct?. try post your routes file and form tag

Comment: routes file:

    `Route::get('/profile', 'UsersController@index');
    Route::post('/profile', 'UsersController@updateAvatar');`


Form:
 `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile" method="POST">
                      <label>Mudar foto</label>
                      <input type="file" name="avatar">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  </form> `

@SSuhat

Comment: @JoãoCosta if you want, try create new laravel project and put the code see if it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this::

```
 use App\User;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use Auth;
 use Image;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

 public function updateAvatar(Request $request){
     $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
     if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){
         $avatar = Input::file('avatar');
         $filename=time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

         if($user->avatar!='default.jgp'){
             $file = 'uploads/avatars/' . $user->avatar;
             if(File::exists($file)){
                 unlink($file);
             }
         }
         Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));
         $user= Auth::user();
         $user->avatar=$filename;
         $user->save();
     }
     return view('pages.AfterLogin.Entidade.users.profile')->withUser(Auth::user());
 }
```

Hope this work for you!